# Extrude Buffer Geometry in Three.js?

Tags: three.js, geometry, buffer-geometry

I recently went back through a scene, replacing all the creations of
`new THREE.SphereGeometry()` 
with buffer geometries: `new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry()`
(cylinder, circle, box, etc.) down the line for all my geometries.

Hit a snag creating `new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry()`

Is there a buffered version of `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry`? And how do I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have my answer: You create the extrude geometry first, then create a buffer geometry from it.

This example assumes you have already extruded a geometry called "extrugeom":

```
var buffgeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
buffgeom.fromGeometry(extrugeom);
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
var mes = new THREE.Mesh(buffgeom, mat);
```